# How can I find input elements which have not been changed in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to find all form elements, with a specific class, and check if they have been altered or not. The if-statement does its job, but I have no idea to correct the find thingy. Is this in the right direction or have I got it all wrong?

```
$("input").find(".formWithMyClass").load(function () {
    if (this.value !== this.defaultValue) {
        $(this).addClass("inactiveForm");
    }
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom selector...

```
(function($) {
    $.expr[':'].defaultValue = function(obj) {
       return obj.value === obj.defaultValue;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you should be able to do `$('input:defaultValue')` to get all `input` elements of whom their `value` property is set to `defaultValue`.

However, if you want to find all input type elements, you may want to extend that custom selector.

I can't seem to find a way to get `select` element's original values (not without setting them up first and foremost). Their `defaultValue` property is `undefined` and `selectedIndex` could be the last chosen value.

Comment: +1 Elegant solution. The the inverse could be used if OP wants to easily check *any* altered field exists.

Comment: Unbelivable how clean that is! Is it possible to restrict it to a certain class or id to prevent it from affecting all forms on my site?

Comment: @Industrial Yes, try this `$('#my-form input:defaultValue')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('form.formWithMyClass input').each(function() {
        if (this.value !== this.defaultValue) {
            $(this).closest('form').addClass("inactiveForm");
        }
    });
});
```

If you have a `<form class="formWithMyClass">` with `<input />` s in it.

```
$(function() {
    $('input.formWithMyClass').each(function() {
        if (this.value !== this.defaultValue) {
            $(this).closest('form').addClass("inactiveForm");
        }
    });
});
```

If you have a `<form>` with `<input class="formWithMyClass" />` s in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also be aware of things like select menus etc.. 
Look at .val( value ) in the JQuery API